What is a $ZZ$-interaction physically?
To me it is clear that a Hamiltonian of the form $H = J \sigma_x$ corresponds to a rotation of a qubit around the $x$-axis. I can substitute the above Hamiltonian into the Schrodinger equation, choose the optimal evolution time for a certain rotation, and see the time evolution of the qubit on the Bloch sphere.
However, when there is some Hamiltonian of the form $H = \sum_{ij} J_i J_j \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z$, I struggle to understand what this Hamiltonian is doing. What exactly is a "$ZZ$ interaction"? The second Hamiltonian I gave is sometimes called an "all-to-all" Hamiltonian which is clear since the summation runs through all the two-level systems in the total interacting system. What does it mean for all the two-level systems to be interacting with each other with "$ZZ$ interactions"?
Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how these abstract Pauli operators can actually represent real-life interactions, and any help clearing this up would be very appreciated!

Writing $H_{ij} = J_{ij} \sigma^z_i \sigma^z_j$, so $H = \sum_{ij} H_{ij}$, lets focus on one particlar $H_{ij}$. This is the $4\times 4$ matrix $$H_{ij} =J_{ij}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}}_{
\hspace{3pt}
|\uparrow \uparrow \rangle\hspace{8pt} 
|\uparrow \downarrow \rangle\hspace{8pt}
|\downarrow \uparrow \rangle\hspace{8pt}
|\downarrow \downarrow \rangle}\hspace{5pt}$$
Recall that the Hamiltonian does two distinct things. If we exponentiate this, we see that it rotates states with aligned spins with a phase, and states with anti-aligned spins with the opposite phase. In particular, if $J_{ij} > 0$, then the ground state will prefer to have spins $i$ and $j$ be anti-aligned in the z-direction. Summing over $i,j$ then summarizes this effect of correlations in the spins on the energy summed over all the spins.
If instead, for example, we had a $\sigma^x_i \sigma^z_j$ interaction, the same logic would apply for a preference of coupling between spin right-up and left-down. So this kind of interaction will appear whenever we have a lattice of spins whose energy depends on the correlation of pairs of spins in the lattice.
